# How do I modify an array in front-end and write back to Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a to-do style app. I have a createCard function that should do three things.

1. Read my firestore doc
2. Modify my labels array
3. Write it back to firestore

Here's my current code:

```
const createCard = async (name, tags) => {
    // READ FIRESOTRE DOC
    const querySnapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid));
    // MODIFY LABELS ARRAY IN FRONT-END
    console.log(querySnapshot.data().labels[activeLabel]);
    const newCard = querySnapshot
      .data()
      .labels[activeLabel].cards.push({ name: name, tags: tags });
    // WRITE MODIFIED ARRAY BACK TO FIRESTORE
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
      newCard,
    });
    console.log(newCard);
    console.log(labels);
    getCards();
    console.log("Tags Created");
  };
```

My desired functionality is for the function to re-write the first (0) array for 'NBA' with an addition of a 3rd card that includes name and tags:

[image]

Instead my function does this, indicated with the blue arrow. I have no idea why newCard = 3?:

[image]

Let me know if I'm missing key information that would be helpful for adding context to my question. Thank you in advance for any advice or help formatting.

Comment: did you mean `querySnapshot.data().labels[activeLabel].cards.push({ name: name, tags: tags })` ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I updated my code to include your update, and now the error is gone - however it still doesn't produce the desired functionality so I added a bit more info.

Comment: I don't have any idea on firebase tbh, but digging through docs - how about using [array Union](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) ?

Comment: Apparently  I cannot use arrayUnion. I need to read the data, modify the data, then write it back somehow. These steps are the only way to update an item in an array in Firestore. I just can't get my logic right.